# Passing image files in Case Statement - Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have several images(1,2,3,4) and would like to pass these images within a switch statement I have written. However, I would like to push the C# code to the Razor Page content(Purchase.cshtml)

The code below exists in my Purchase.cs file

```
public void OnGet(int PizzaType, int PizzaCount)
{
    switch (PizzaType)
    {
            case 1:
                PizzaName = "BBQ Beef";
                PizzaCount = (int)(PizzaCount * 10.50);
                break;
            case 2:
                PizzaName = "Chicken and Pineapple";
                PizzaCount = (int)(PizzaCount * 8.50);
                break;
            case 3:
                PizzaName = "Pepperoni Feast";
                PizzaCount = (int)(PizzaCount * 9.0);
                break;
            case 4:
                PizzaName = "Vegeterian";
                PizzaCount = (int)(PizzaCount * 7.0);
                break;
    }

    ViewData["TotalPrice"] = PizzaCount;
    ViewData["PizzaType"] = PizzaName;
}
```

How do I achieve this:
I have tried the below but no results.

```
<p>You purchased @ViewData["PizzaType"] </p>

@{
    int PizzaType = 1;
    string ImageFile;

    switch (PizzaType)
    {
        case 1:
            ImageFile = "<img src='~/images/1.jpg'>";
            break;
        case 2:
            ImageFile = "<img src='~/images/2.jpg'>";
            break;
        case 3:
            ImageFile = "<img src='~/images/3.jpg'>";
            break;
        case 4:
            ImageFile = "<img src='~/images/4.jpg'>";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error you are getting with this code?

Comment: where is PizzaName declared, are you trying to set image file name or image tag for rendering?

Comment: @coder_b Pizza name was declared. The first piece of code works, the second however, =jamshaid Kamran doesn't yield any results at all.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be working fine but it won't render your `img` tag because you are just saving it in a variable of type `string`. To render html that you have in `string` variable, you can use the `Html` helper method like below:

```
int PizzaType = 1;
string ImageFile = ""; // Modify it to be empty as mvc would cause problem with unsigned variables.

switch (PizzaType)
{
    case 1:
        ImageFile = "<img src='~/images/1.jpg'>";
        break;
    case 2:
        ImageFile = "<img src='~/images/2.jpg'>";
        break;
    case 3:
        ImageFile = "<img src='~/images/3.jpg'>";
        break;
    case 4:
        ImageFile = "<img src='~/images/4.jpg'>";
        break;
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageFile))
{
    @Html.Raw(ImageFile) @* And Render your html like this *@
}
```

Or you can directly render it without copying it in your variable like below:

```
@int PizzaType = 1;

@switch (PizzaType)
{
    case 1:
        <img src='~/images/1.jpg'>
        break;
    case 2:
        <img src='~/images/2.jpg'>
        break;
    case 3:
        <img src='~/images/3.jpg'>
        break;
    case 4:
        <img src='~/images/4.jpg'>
        break;
}
```

Or to make it even short, what you can do is use your `PizzaType` variable to generate the `src` and get rid of the `switch` statement. This is the one liner for your `switch` statement:

```
<img src='~/images/@string.Format("{0}.jpg", PizzaType)'>
```